# How to degauss a distributor

Tags: chevrolet, ignition, suburban

I have a 1994 Chevy Suburban that is stalling after a short warm up. I finally put it in the back yard until I get a new idea, but without going into the problem and what I have tried (which includes many obvious things that I might go into that later), I wanted to check out a hunch.

I ran across a mention of replacing the distributor or degaussing it. I guess after many years some distributors become magnetized. If they use electronic ignition that uses a magnetic pickup, then they won't run right. My truck has that kind of ignition.

Can someone explain how I can degauss my distributor and where would I get the degaussing equipment?

(Okay, I have done several things already. I have replaced the fuel pump, the fuel filter, the fuel pump relay, the spark plugs, the spark plug wires, the rotor, the distributor cap, and the EGR valve. There are some other things I have done that I can't remember right now. I have not replaced the injectors, which appear to be working fine on visual inspection. I like to tinker, but I obviously have given up for awhile. But this degaussing idea has me intrigued.)

Comment: Does it restart after stalling? If it doesn't start have you determined if it a spark or fuel issue?

Comment: It will only restart if I spray some ether into the throttle body (or wait a long time, I guess). I think there is some feedback problem. It runs very smooth for a few minutes and then dies. If I can keep the rpm up above normal idle, I can keep it running smooth all day. But at idle, it will die after a fe minutes.

Comment: The fact that it keeps running if you keep the RPM up instead of letting it idle suggests to me that it's not necessarily an ignition fault. Have you check the idle control valve?

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in the comments, I don't thing the problem resides in the distributor, but in the Idle Air Control (IAC) valve. It either needs to be replaced or it needs to be cleaned and adjusted. Be careful when removing/cleaning/adjusting, as the gears inside are *very* fragile. It doesn't take much to push the plunger in and cause an issue. I believe the main shaft is on a screw, so you can adjust it by turning it clockwise/counterclockwise. If you just push it it, the gears inside will be destroyed.